# How to make login code in java

Tags: java

I'm  trying to make login code in java but there's some problem in my code.
If I enter correct data or wrong one still can't enter the loop to 
go to next frame.
This is full code it's already have exception so it's not the problem .

```
Connection conn = null ;
try 
{
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DB?"+
                          "user=name&password=pass&characterEncoding=utf8");

    String query = ("Select User_Name from user where User_Name = '" + txtUserName + "' 
                   and password = '" + passwordField.getPassword().toString() + "' ; ");

    PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
    while (rs.wasNull()) {
        System.out.println("true");
        frame2.setVisible(true);
        frame.setVisible(false);
        break;
    }
}
catch (SQLException ee)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame2, "Wrong inf ... please try again ");
}
```

I try this too but still not working.

```
Connection conn  = null ;
try 
{
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DB?"+
                        "user=name&password=pass&characterEncoding=utf8");

    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    String query = "Select User_Name from user where User_Name =? and password=?";
    stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
    stmt.setString(1, txtUserName.getText());
    stmt.setString(2, passwordField.getPassword().toString());
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

    while (rs.next()) {
        System.out.println("true");
        frame2.setVisible(true);
        frame.setVisible(false);
        break;
    }                       
}
catch (SQLException ee)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame2, "Wrong inf ... please try again ");
}
```

Comment: Debug your program please. It's impossible for anyone to guess what's wrong here.

Comment: is there any exception? if there are no exceptions, the select then is the problem.. is returning 0 records

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really a Java programmer but a quick glance at your code and the descriptions of ResultSet::wasNull() ResultSet::next() show me you're misusing or misunderstanding how those work.

1. wasNull() tells you if the current column contains a null. An empty set is **not** null!
2. next() moves the cursor forward one row and returns true if the **new** current row is valid. False otherwise. In other words, if you have zero or one valid row, next() will immediately return false.

So, let's put things together.

Case 1: Using wasNull():

- Enter valid data. ResultSet contains a non-null result. wasNull() returns false, don't enter while loop.
- Enter invalid data. ResultSet contains an empty set result. wasNull() returns false, don't enter while loop.

Case 2: Using next():

- Enter valid data. ResultSet contains a single non-null result. next() moves to next row [which is invalid] and returns false, don't enter while loop.
- Enter invalid data. ResultSet contains a single empty set result. next() moves to next row [which is invalid] and returns false, don't enter while loop.

Might I suggest spending some time reading the ResultSet API documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html